# Obtain information from JSON Array to use in Google maps based Android application

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

Hey guys sorry that the title isn't the best. Basically there is a web service running at a particular url that returns a JSON array with a single object. Each object is an array containing name, longitude and latitude of people.

How can I use this in the MapsActivity in Android Studio to display the user's locations on Google maps? I have already created several other activities for the rest of the application (welcome screens, etc.) but I'm a bit stuck on this part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading the JSON? Look into Google's GSON.

Comment: @Matthew Ok thank you I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from Google's GSON, you can also try android's `Volley`. There are many tutorials for that as well. You'll just need to get the library for volley. Here's an example code:

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                    String  name, longitude, latitude;
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            name = object.getString("name");
                            longitude = object.getString("longitude");
                            latitude = object.getString("latitude");
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);//this is a singleton class
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a look into Volley as well and thanks for the example code

Comment: No problem at all! Glad to help you :)